# Script tag not loading content in nextjs but working fine in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, react-widgets

I am trying to use a widget that I have created in reactjs using script tags like below-

**React Implementation**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

const Dust = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <link
          href="https://master--testasdfasdfadsf.netlify.app/widget/index.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script
          async
          src="https://master--testasdfasdfadsf.netlify.app/widget/index.js"
        ></script>
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dust;
```

For react js the above is working fine and I can see the content on my screen.

**NextJs Implementation**

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Script from "next/script";
import Head from "next/head";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main
      className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 ${inter.className}`}
    >
      <Head>
        <link
          href="https://master--testasdfasdfadsf.netlify.app/widget/index.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </Head>
      <Script
        src="https://master--testasdfasdfadsf.netlify.app/widget/index.js"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

The above is not working in next js, however I can see the js and css loading in network tab. What might be the solution in nextjs?

Comment: I am receiving the same exact error in both snippets

Comment: Which version of React and NextJS? Are you using the pages or app router?

Comment: @grekier Could be any but I am using pages layout for now.  "next": "14.1.3",
    "react": "^18",

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. Actually I created the widget with id="root" in my index.html file inside public folder. So to use that from a script, there must be any id="root" element too or any name any name of your choice.